# Nested structs with methods using templates

Tags: c++, struct

I want to translate python nested defs to c++, which I am doing using nested structs.

```
#include<iostream>
static void ffunc(int x, int y)
{
    static int x1 = x;
    static int y1 = y;
    struct g
    {
        static void gfunc(int z)
        {
            static int z1 = z;
            std::cout << x1 << y1 << z << std::endl;

            struct h
            {
                static void hfunc(int k)
                {
                    std::cout<< x1 << y1 << z1 << k <<  std::endl;
                }
            };
            h::hfunc(4);
        }
    };
    g::gfunc(3);
}
int main()
{
    ffunc(1, 2);
}
```

This code works fine. The problem is, I want to templates, so that the nested functions can use any type parameters. However, when I try to use templates:

```
#include<iostream>
template <typename t1>
static void ffunc(t1 x, t1 y)
{
    static t1 x1 = x;
    static t1 y1 = y;
    struct g
    {
        static void gfunc(int z)
        {
            static int z1 = z;
            std::cout << x1 << y1 << z << std::endl;

            struct h
            {
                static void hfunc(int k)
                {
                    std::cout<< x1 << y1 << z1 << k <<  std::endl;
                }
            };
            h::hfunc(4);
        }
    };
    g::gfunc(3);
}
int main()
{
    ffunc(1, 2);
}
```

I get the error:

```
/tmp/cceIMovo.o: In function `void ffunc<int>(int, int)::g::gfunc(int)':
nested.cc:(.text+0x17d): undefined reference to `y1'
nested.cc:(.text+0x183): undefined reference to `x1'
/tmp/cceIMovo.o: In function `void ffunc<int>(int, int)::g::gfunc(int)::h::hfunc(int)':
nested.cc:(.text+0x1e5): undefined reference to `z1'
nested.cc:(.text+0x1ec): undefined reference to `y1'
nested.cc:(.text+0x1f2): undefined reference to `x1'
```

Does anyone know if what I want to do is possible in c++? Thanks!

Comment: Since C++ is a compiled language (and because of language design decisions), nesting structs (and particularly methods in those structs) have consequences. I strongly suggest that you learn about "inline functions" to understand the pros and cons of designing your code in this way.

Comment: @MegaJoules: not often a stackoverflow question finds an honest-to-goodness compiler bug.

Comment: @MooingDuck : Unless we're talking about VC++. :-P

Comment: @MooingDuck What compiler bug? I believe this code is only allowed in C++11, not C++03 (linkage problem of class templates inside functions).

Comment: While I can understand the theoretical interest in this question, I doubt whether writing python in C++ is the right way to solve your underlying problem. If you describe more completely the real design/implementation problem you're experiencing perhaps we can give you a C++-idiomatic solution.

Answer (score 2):

I might be wrong, but this looks like a compiler bug. GCC (4.7.2) produces that error, while Clang (3.1) and ICC (13.0.0) deal just fine with it.

Minimal code for trying to reproduce this on other compilers: http://pastebin.com/kf2sF3NL

Comment: I am limited to using GCC 4.4.6

Comment: @MegaJoules So this bug is not a recent regression. (If it is a bug.) I posted about this on the GCC mailing list. The minimal code that reproduces this btw is: http://pastebin.com/kf2sF3NL

Comment: @NikosC.: link to the bug report?

Comment: @MooingDuck It just showed up on GMane: http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gcc.g++.general/5281